# c++ assigning vector pointers to map of vector pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dictionary

I have a pointer pointing to map of vector pointers:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<object *> > *m_mapvals;
```

and different number of vector pointers:

```
int vecval = 1; 
std::vector<object *> *m_vecvals;
```

For each vector pointer, I use a unique integer number and I want each vector pointer to point to one entry in the map with the key that is assigned. How could I achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Why the vector pointers as well as the map? Why not just look the vector up in the map when you need it?

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated data structure.

Comment: Are you asking how to look things up in a map?

Comment: Actually, I have a receiving thread which receives all the data and put it into the map and send a signal to the observer thread. Meanwhile when observer thread receives the signal, it will check the vector pointer in order to get the data for itself. I just want to link these two data structures.

Comment: I guess that in order to be able to synchronize access to your data, you'll have to look it up in the map using the key.

Comment: And probably lock everything and therefore make it slower than just having one thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Foo{
public:
    int number;

    Foo(int number){
        this->number = number;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // structure
    std::map<int, std::vector<Foo*>>* m_mapvals;
    // and its init.
    m_mapvals = new std::map<int, std::vector<Foo*>>();

    // one record
    int vecval = 1;
    std::vector<Foo *>* vecvals = new std::vector<Foo*>(); // init
    vecvals->push_back(new Foo(42)); // fill with values

    // insert record into structure
    m_mapvals->insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<Foo*>>(vecval, *vecvals));

    // first at() selects the record, therefore result is vector
    // the second at selects the first Foo object pointer from the vector
    std::cout << "Number is: " << m_mapvals->at(1).at(0)->number;

    return 0;
}
```

This solves your problem, however, I strongly recommend not to use so many pointers. You will most probably lose control of the memory. You use m_ suffix, therefore I guess that main map is an object attribute. Usually, there is no advantage to have pointer on map or vector between the attributes. If you want to create dynamically changing collection of object this could be better and simpler:

```
class Collection{
   std::map<int, std::vector<Foo*>> m_myCollection
}
```

or if there is no problem with cloning of stored objects, the most secure is

```
class Collection{
   std::map<int, std::vector<Foo>> m_myCollection
}
```

But this depends on the gist of the problem. Nonetheless, here is no problem with memory management. If you create instance of this class using new, whole object will be on heap.